# update role app users in Azure AD using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, powerapps, graph-explorer

I have different roles of an app called power.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s35M.png)

Each user has a role assigned and I want to be able to change a role to a user with graph api using graph explorer and connect it to power apps.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiRHy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0OcB.png)

With this request i have the id role of all users but I don't know how to update them

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{id}/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/%7Bid%7D/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments)

If there is another api or connector with which I can do it and connect it with powerapps, it also works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be sending a request as below (from [Grant an appRoleAssignment for a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http))

**Endpoint**

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{appObjectId}/appRoleAssignedTo`

`{appObjectId}` should be the **Enterprise Application** (service principal) object ID

**Method**

`POST`

**Request headers**

```
Content-type: application/json
```

**Request Body**

```
{
    "principalId": "",
    "resourceId": "",
    "appRoleId": ""
}
```

`principalId` = The user/group object ID

`resourceId` = The **Enterprise Application** object ID, which is the same ID used in the endpoint `{appObjectId}`

`appRoleId` = The app role ID, which can be found in the **App Registration** manifest

Comment: Thank you very much for responding but this does not update, it gives one more role to the user
Isn't there a way to update the same role?

Comment: @Imad I can't find any way to do so. You can remove the other role with an additional call using the Delete method